# Does Windows 10 move files from folder to folder on the same local internal disk by relinking file pointers or copy-then-delete?

Tags: windows-10

I ask because I thought the move operation locally was more like the rename process, simply relink a few file pointers and be done with it.

I am in the process of setting up my Windows 10 machine after upgrading to a bigger SSD drive and in the process of setting up Dropbox with 300+ GB of files the recommended procedure said to simply pause the sync, move all the old contents into the new folder and resume sync.

Yet the move take ages. Judging by the data I can see in the move dialog, it seems the move process copies the file and then deletes it.

Yet, as stated, I thought the move operation since this is the same disk, was simply a file pointer relinking.

So, the question is this:

1. Was my assumption wrong? Move is really copy-then-delete?
2. Is there a setting wrong somewhere?
3. Could something be intefering with the relinking process, like the files belong to an older installation and thus have access data or ownership data that Windows can delete but doesn't really want to bring along?

Note, this is the same physical drive, same logical drive, same Windows drive, etc. No shenanigans here.

The process I used was:

1. I swapped out my primary drive with a bigger SSD
2. The Dropbox folder was located on my secondary drive, D:\Dropbox
3. After installing Windows 10 on the primary drive I renamed D:\Dropbox to D:\DropboxOld
4. I then installed Dropbox and asked it to sync to D:\Dropbox (parallel folder to D:\DropboxOld)
5. I then paused sync and started moving contents from D:\DropboxOld to D:\Dropbox (as per this article: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/1941)

And this is currently where I'm at, waiting for this move to complete.

The reason I figure it is really copying-then-deleting is that first and foremost it takes ages to complete but primarily I notice that when it hits a big file, like say the SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition ISO file, the move dialog looks like this:

```
Items remaining: 27 (6,00 GB)
```

Then it simply starts counting down the GB's left until it is finished with the file. If the move was a simple relink it would quickly move on to the next file, but it doesn't. The files remaining stays at 27 until the GB's have counted down the size of that iso.

Comment: I've noticed that moving a 3GB+ file takes about a second while copying it can take 5 minutes. Beyond that I can't help much.

Comment: Moving a 3GB file here takes a few minutes, so again it seems it is actually copying the file (and then deleting it), not just doing a quick relink.

Comment: That's certainly strange. I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Ownership was indeed old user so I'm taking ownership and resetting ACL's on all the files and folders now, will see if this improves the process.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I can still see the move dialog counting down MB's left while retaining the files left, meaning that it moves the file piece by piece and not as a unit.

Comment: That's really strange. Maybe try reindexing that area or something?

Comment: You say "same disk" but actually it is "Same filesystem". If you move from C: to D:, even if both are on the same disk it is still a copy+delete. Besides that: Windows Explorer is just about the slowest file-manager ever. It might be a LOT faster if you use an alternative file-manager. (Don't use FreeCommander though. It copies by calling Explorer so that doesn't make a difference.)

Comment: No, same disk and partition. I created my Dropbox folder in the root of my data drive, D:, and I kept this drive. After reinstalling Windows 10 on my new SSD, the C: drive, I renamed D:\Dropbox to D:\DropboxOld, then installed Dropbox and made it create a new Dropbox folder in the D: root. This is the same physical drive, the same partition, the same logical Windows drive, just two parallel folders.